# Add HTTP-Request parameters to Span

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Is there a convenient and scalable way to add certain parameters (e.g. HTTP-request header information or parameters) or user Information to the Spans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use tags to add arbitrary values to spans. Also check this section of the documentation (http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_customizations) how you can extract and inject values to / from span / http requests

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that leads me into the right direction I guess what I want to do is similar to what the `TraceFilter` is currently doing. Just modify the `addRequestTags` and `addResponseTags`. Do you know whether there is a recommended way to do that, or do I have to create my own implementation of GenericFilterBean as suggested in the Documentation example for the `HttpResponseInjectingTraceFilter` found in your link?

Comment: Yeah try doing it like presented in the docs. If you have any problems ping me back and we'll also update the docs.

Comment: I managed to write a filter that writes the params of a servlet to a span - just what I wanted. Thank you so much. However I am not quite sure how precise the information on filter registration in the HTTP example of the documentation is. I am fairly new to all this. But I needed some search to figure out where to correctly place the `@Bean` part. And I could not figure out how it works to just put the `Tracer` as argument of the `@Bean` method. I ended up creating a `@Autowired` field for the tracer and used this to create the filter.

Comment: You can register the filter in a similar way as we do here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebAutoConfiguration.java#L87-L95

Comment: Is there a suggested way to add a HandlerInterceptorAdapter like `TraceHandlerInterceptor`?

Comment: You can do it in the same as we do - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceWebMvcConfigurer.java#L37-L45

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, but was not able to identify in the Repo. Thank you.